# remove non repeating characters from a list

Tags: python

I am trying to remove non repeating characters from a list in python. e.g list = [1,1,2,3,3,3,5,6] should return [1,1,3,3].
My initial attempt was:

```
def tester(data):
    for x in data:
        if data.count(x) == 1:
            data.remove(x)
    return data
```

This will work for some inputs, but for [1,2,3,4,5], for example, it returns [2,4]. Could someone please explain why this occurs?

Comment: also, your approach is O(n^2) which is probably not what you want

Comment: You should not change a list while you do loop through its elements. That is why you got [2,4]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 l=[1,1,2,3,3,3,5,6]

 [x for x in l if l.count(x) > 1] 
 [1, 1, 3, 3, 3]
```

Adds elements that appear  at least twice in your list.

In your own code you need to change the line `for x in data` to `for x in data[:]:`

Using `data[:]` you are iterating over a `copy` of  original list.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but perhaps it was for suggesting a quadratic time solution in place of a linear time one. If the list is always very short, the quadratic performance won't really matter, but in the general case it's very important

Comment: @gnibbler,the question was not what is the most efficient way to remove non repeating  elements  from a list. It was about why the OP's code was not  working, I provided two ways to get around it so I think downvoting is still bs.

Answer (score 4):

There is a linear time solution for that:

```
def tester(data):
    cnt = {}
    for e in data:
        cnt[e] = cnt.get(e, 0) + 1
    return [x for x in data if cnt[x] > 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is occurring because you are removing from a list as you're iterating through it. Instead, consider appending to a new list.

You could also use collections.Counter, if you're using 2.7 or greater:

```
[a for a, b in collections.Counter(your_list).items() if b > 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another linear solution.

```
>>> data = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6]
>>> D = dict.fromkeys(data, 0)
>>> for item in data:
...     D[item] += 1
... 
>>> [item for item in data if D[item] > 1]
[1, 1, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't remove items from a mutable list while iterating over that same list. The interpreter doesn't have any way to keep track of where it is in the list while you're doing this.

See [this question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python) for another example of the same problem, with many suggested alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the list comprehention,just like this:

```
def tester(data):
    return [x for x in data if data.count(x) != 1]
```

it is not recommended to remove item when iterating